# What does at @ mean in MATLAB when creating an instance of a class?

Tags: matlab, oop

For example:

```
function s = slexpdatasetSLAP()
    s = s@slexpdataset('slapCC','SLAP dataset for collective classification'); %slexpdataset is a class defined in another .m file
    s.discription ='CC';
end
```

As I know, `@` is used as creating a function handle in MATLAB, but obviously that interpretation is not suitable in this context. So what does that at `@` mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the syntax for calling [the constructor of the super-class](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/calling-superclass-methods-on-subclass-objects.html#bsa1tzj)

In general, [for calling a method of the superclass](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/calling-superclass-methods-on-subclass-objects.html#bu_b_za-1), you'd use the syntax

```
outputs = methodName@superclassname(obj, input, arguments)
```

However, calling the constructor is a *little* different since you use the variable name for your object's instance in place of `methodName` in the example above

```
obj = obj@superclassname(input, arguments)
```

In your case, rather than `obj`, you're using `s` as the variable to refer to the class instance (since you define that as the output from your constructor), so you're essentially calling the constructor of `slexpdataset` and passing it the list of arguments shown.